# Why is my infinite scroll loading extra images after final image has been reached with jquery and php?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a database with 25 prompts(this value won't stay 25 as users can post prompts)

I want these prompts to be displayed on index.html and I want it to be an infinite scroll so the user can keep scrolling and see new prompts.

I'm trying to do this using jquery and php.

When I scroll down new images get loaded correctly until it reaches the 25th(last) prompt in the database and then it loads random prompts.

**This is what I see when I inspect:**

[image]

I don't even have an img=26 and higher in my database but it says img=28,29,30 etc.
I have noticed its always 17 images that get displayed after the last image from the database.

**I have this jquery in my index.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      var offset = 0;
      var amount = 10;
      var working = false;
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "showcase.php?offset=" + offset + "&amount=" + amount,
          processData: false,
          contentType: "application/json",
          data: "",
          success: function (r) {
            console.log(r);
            r = JSON.parse(r);
            for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
              $("body").append("<img src='" + r[i].cover_url + "' />");
            }
            offset += 10;
            amount += 10;
          },
          error: function (r) {
            console.log("Something went wrong!");
          },
        });
      });
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (
          $(this).scrollTop() + 1 >=
          $("body").height() - $(window).height()
        ) {
          if (working == false) {
            working = true;
            $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "showcase.php?offset=" + offset + "&amount=" + amount,
              processData: false,
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: "",
              success: function (r) {
                r = JSON.parse(r);
                for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                  $("body").append("<img src='" + r[i].cover_url + "' />");
                }
                offset += 10;
                amount += 10;
                setTimeout(function () {
                  working = false;
                }, 100);
              },
              error: function (r) {
                console.log("Something went wrong!");
              },
            });
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
```

**and showcase.php has this code:**

```
include_once("classes/Db.php");
class Prompt {
        public static function filter($offset, $limit){
                $conn = Db::getInstance();
                $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM prompts LIMIT $offset, $limit");
                $stmt->execute();
                $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            
}



$offset = $_GET['offset'];
$amount = $_GET['amount'];
$prompts = Prompt::filter($offset, $amount);

//echo "<pre>";
echo json_encode(Prompt::filter($offset, $amount));
```

Thankyou for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For limit, it should be a fixed value. Because you increase amount using amount += 10, the process will be:

Turn 1: offset = 0, amount = 10 -> it will get 10 images, start from offset 0

Turn 2: offset = 10, amount = 20 -> it will get 20 images, start from offset 10

Turn 3: offset = 20, amount = 30 -> it will get 30 images, start from offset 20

....

**So**, remove amount += 10 in ajax success:

```
 success: function (r) {
     console.log(r);
     r = JSON.parse(r);
     for (var i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
         $("body").append("<img src='" + r[i].cover_url + "' />");
      }
      offset += 10;
  },
```